# roslaunch xml: how to pass a list of strings as parameters?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to pass a list of strings as an argument in a launch file? Something like

```
<launch>
  <arg name="source_list" default="[a_topic,a_second_topic]"/>
  <node>
     <param name="source_list" value="$(arg source_list)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213185/roslaunch-xml:-how-to-pass-a-list-of-strings-as-parameters?/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="source_list" default="[a_topic,a_second_topic]"/>

    <node ...>

         <rosparam param="source_list" subst_value="True">$(arg source_list)</rosparam> 

    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tiki](https://answers.ros.org/users/34270/tiki/) with karma: 76 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rosparam. There is an example given here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2